When we say that two terms are not unified?
I didn't understand well the cases where two terms are not unified, for exemple why $$P(y, y) \text { and } P(f(x), b)$$ are not unified terms?
Because with $$\sigma=(b\mapsto f(x))$$ we will have : $$P(y, y) \text { and } P(b, b)$$ so the two terms are unified.

Unification is based on the operation of Substitution that maps variables to terms. This means that we may put $b$ in place of $x$ but not in place of $f(x)$.

but f(x) according to our course is a term?

so,why we can't put b in place of f(x)

Unification is based on the operation of substitution that maps variables to terms.
This means that we may put a term $b$ in place of variable $x$, but not in place of another term $f(x)$.
This, with $σ= (x ↦ b, y ↦ b)$ from $P(y,y) , P(f(x),b)$ we get $P(b,b), P(f(b),b)$.
